# AndroidX Lifecycle Error, how do i solve it?

Tags: java, android

[image]

I already tried to put all lifecycle dependencies and it didn't resolve

Dependencies:

```
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // AndroidX
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0-rc03'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.2.0-rc03'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.2.0-rc03'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.2.0-rc03'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.2.0-rc03'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-reactivestreams:2.2.0-rc03'
    implementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.1.0'

    // Google
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha10'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'

    // Okhttp
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.2.2'
```

Comment: Are you using android.useAndroidX=true android.enableJetifier=true n your gradle.properties

Comment: Unfortunately I don't use Android Studio yet, I use Android IDE

Comment: go to your root directory there you will find  gradle.properties.

Comment: AppCompat 1.1.0 is too old. If you are using 2.2.0-RC3 for the lifecycle libs, this should match your AppCompat version too.

Comment: How to match versions?